# how to search camel case data in oracle database search query?

Tags: database, oracle, select, oracle10g

this is my search query

Below search query returns products Because 'iPhone' is case sensitive

```
SELECT productname,id FROM products where productname LIKE '%iPhone%'
```

Below search query returns **ZERO** products Because 'iPhone' is case sensitive

```
SELECT productname,id FROM products where productname LIKE 'IPHONE%' or  productname LIKE '%iphone%'
```

If i used UPPER or LOWER function it returns zero, so how can I solve this issue ?

How Can I solve camel case sensitive data in oracle database query. I can not change the product name in database. Anyone have solution for this ?
If you have doubt in my question please ask me I will instant reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT productname, id 
FROM products 
WHERE LOWER(productname) LIKE LOWER('%iPhone%')
```

should return *something*. Note `LOWER` function on both sides of `LIKE`.